# Htaccess rule for pretty url in sub folder html file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am currently trying to make pretty url and I tried code from other post and was successful to rewrite using below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?g/(.*?)/?$ /g.html?name=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /g\.html\?name=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?g\.html$ /g/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

It changes my main folder g.html?name=this into g/this but I need to rewrite html file in my sub folder which is /sub/w.html plz help to make it aslo sub/w/this

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please post samples of urls; eg: FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect OR rewrite, that will help us to understand your question better, thank you.

Comment: I want to redirect from https://mydomain/new/w?name=jaaj to https://mydomain/new/jaaj where new is the subfolder in my domain @RavinderSingh13

Comment: And this url in backend should be served from which file?

Comment: sorry it should be redirect to https://mydomain/new/w/jaaj  where it should be served with w.html which is on /new/w.html folder @RavinderSingh13

Comment: No only html file sir @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Please take a look and also plz share some websites or videos where I can learn more about these stuffs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place these rules at top of your htaccess rules file and try checking your URLs. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also make sure to keep your htaccess file along with new folder(not inside it, along with it).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(new)/w\?name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(name)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2.html [L]
```

***NOTE:*** I am matching specifically matching name folder here in Rule because your already existing rules also have checks for non-existing pages, so didn't want to conflict it.

Comment: Along with means the htaccess at main folder?

Comment: @Webnair, means new folder and htaccess should be in same folder. Example: `/singh/test/.htaccess` and `/singh/test/new` just example to show what I meant.